# Calculating Employee Pay Using Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, function, console-application

I have two arrays `payArray`, `hoursArray`, where the arrays are initialized by reading in from a `csv` file.

The goal is to `calculate base pay` which would be the `payArray` times the `hoursArray`. The problem is that the hoursArray contains hours that are over 40. Any hours over 40 get over time which is 1.5 per hour more. So I have to calculate base pay, `over time pay` and `gross pay` using these two arrays.

Currently I have the following function:

Note * numOfEmployees = 20 and OT_RATE = 1.5

```
static double BasePay()
{
  int i;
  double bpay;

  for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
  {
    if (hoursArray[i] > 40)
      hoursArray[i] * OT_RATE;
    else if

      bpay = payArray[i] * hoursArray[i];

  }
  return bpay;

}
```

I have tried a few different way to calculate these by using this function, but been able to do so.

Update**

Here is the file output and function:

```
for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
    fileOut.WriteLine("{0,4:D4} {1,-25} {2,3} {3,7:f} {4,6:f} {5,6:f}",
                      idArray[i], nameArray[i], deptArray[i], payArray[i], hoursArray[i], BasePay(id));


static double BasePay(int i)
{
  int id = 0;
  double bpay = 0.0, OT_RATE = 1.5;

  if (id < hoursArray.Length) //guard on array index
  {
    if (hoursArray[i] > 40)
      bpay += (hoursArray[i] - 40) * payArray[i] * OT_RATE + (40 * payArray[i]);
    else
      bpay += payArray[i] * hoursArray[i];
  }

  return bpay;
}
```

After adding the reference for `id = 0;` the formula seems to work, but I get the following output:

[Pay Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3laPR.png)

The base pay for Toni (names changed) should be 880.00 which would be 22.00 time 40, then technically the over time would be 132.00 since 4 hours at 1.5 times their pay rate is the OT calculation.

Comment: Did you want bpay to represent the pay of everyone or just one person at a time (in which case it should be an array of base pays)

Comment: @JoePhilllips I want it to loop through each person. That's why I have the for loop with numOfEmployees = 20. In my file output I have a loop that lists each employee, then their pay rate, hours worked, base pay, etc. So this will have to loop through each person. I will have a function for the total of everyone at a later date.

Comment: You get that error because you have not defined `i` as a variable inside the function. I think you meant to use `id` inside your if-else statement instead of `i`

Answer (score 3):

The base pay is going to be calculated as such:

```
for (...)
{
    bpay[i] = payArray[i] * (hoursArray[i] > 40 ? 40 : hoursArray[i]);
}
```

This is what your function should be returning because it is named "BasePay". You shouldn't need to worry about overtime in this particular function.

If you want to rename the function something like `Pay()` then you can do this:

```
for (...)
{
    pay[i] = payArray[i] * (hoursArray[i] > 40 ? 40 : hoursArray[i]);

    if (hoursArray[i] > 40)
        pay[i] += payArray[i] * OT_RATE * (hoursArray[i] - 40);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are intend to get ***just***  last employee base pay or total basepay. Also (I assume) you need *OT_RATE* only after 40 hours.

I updated code assuming you need basepay of all employees and OT applies only for excess of work (40 hours).

```
static double BasePay()
{
  int i;
  double bpay =0.0, OT_RATE = 1.5;


  for (i = 1; i <= numOfEmployees; i++)
  {
      if (hoursArray[i] > 40)
         bpay += (hoursArray[i]-40) * payArray[i] * OT_RATE + (40* payArray[i]);
      else 
         bpay += payArray[i] * hoursArray[i];
  }  return bpay;    
}
```

**Update:**

Alternatively you can also remove loop here to get basepay for individual employee by passing id.

```
static double BasePay(int i)
{
    double bpay =0.0, OT_RATE = 1.5;

    if(id < hoursArray.Length) //guard on array index
    { 
        if (hoursArray[i] > 40)
            bpay += (hoursArray[i]-40) * payArray[i] * OT_RATE + (40* payArray[i]);
        else 
            bpay += payArray[i] * hoursArray[i];            
    }

    return bpay;    
}
```

Comment: I get "Use of unassigned local variable" for the bpay under the if statement.

Comment: I forgot that, we have to initialize the variable before using it. Updated my answer.

Comment: The code works, and makes sense, thank you! I think I may have a problem with an array now. When I call that function now in a writeLine I get the same number 20 times: 27691.71 this should be different for each person, as each person in hoursArray and payArray has a different value. Any thoughts?

Comment: in this case you can pass we should remove for loop in the function, let me give that solution as well.

Comment: see my update in my original post. I think I have just another issue to iron out.

Comment: Updated function parameter name, change your code to use `i ` instead of `id`( in  file writing statement)

Comment: Now it's working, but only on people that work under 40 hours. For example I have the first person in my array that gets 22.00 per hour, worked 44 hours, and the base pay comes to 1766.00 Then there are others that get the right amount which is the payarray times the hours array. I feel like the algorithm is only working on some of them for some reason. I don't see why.

Comment: See update. It's still not calculating correctly. I had to initialize the id variable since the program wouldn't build. There is a link to the image of my out put. You will notice that the base pay is still incorrect. Should I be building an array for each item? Base PAy, Ovt Pay, Gross Pay etc?